# When I try to change the directory on Ubuntu, it won't let me

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, bash, command-history

When I type in

```
cd Desktop/Code
```

and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it says

```
-bash: cd: DesktopCode: No such file or directory
```

I do have that file in my desktop, but I'm not sure how to access it and I'm not sure why it says `-bash` beforehand, and if that has something to do with it.

What is wrong?

Edit: I was confused and mistyped it. The error is "-bash: cd: Desktop/Code: No such file or directory".
I am considering deleting ubuntu and then re-installing it, but I'm not sure if that would be too much of a hassle and if there is another way. Also, thank you to everyone who's helped me! I need to fix this in order to do an assignment and I cannot figure it out and I appreciate it so much.

Comment: What is "Code", a file or a directory? And this has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: What does `cd Desktop//Code` do for you?

Comment: What directory are you in when you do this?  Unless Desktop is a child of your current directory, you will need the complete path.

Answer (score 6):

You have typed a backslash (`\`) in your command instead of a forward slash (`/`).

The backslash is used as an escape character. Since `\C` (in `Desktop\Code`) is not a recognized escape sequence, the backslash is ignored, so your command is interpreted as `cd DesktopCode`.

Comment: Ninja’ed by a dog!    :-(    ⁠

Comment: That's speciesist!

Comment: BARK! BARKBARKBARK!

Comment: According to the original content and the latest edit to make that specific point more clear (I read it for the first time just now anyway), they are indeed already using a forward slash and not a backslash. Why might that happen when that is the case to go along with your existing answer.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT The edits were not made by the OP. The simplest and most likely explanation for the behavior they're describing is that they typed a backslash by mistake.

Comment: I was referring to the original before the edits too... https://i.imgur.com/cs1JaKj.png perhaps that is the case though as it sounds like it to me too so perhaps they stated wrongly what they used there.

Answer (score 0):

There are details that would be helpful, but, since you are new to Unbutu, you would not know them.  Let's try some troubleshooting and see what happens.

At you command prompt, what does your prompt look like? something like this:

[Gabriel@mycomputer] $ _

Can you run a directory listing?

*ls -la*

Can you print the current directory?

*pwd*
-- or --
*cwd*

Next, can you try just a cd command:

*cd ~*

if not, try to "unalias" the cd, like this:

*\cd ~*

Notice the "backslash" before the cd. This is not the "forward slash" that you see with the question mark.
Forward Slash: /
Back Slash: \

And, try this command, just to see what it says:

*which cd*

Can you run any other command successfully, besides cd?

Comment: Hello! Sorry for the late response. I am able to run a directory listing and print the current directory, and my prompt does look like that somewhat. When I run a cd command, it says "-bash: cd:" the directory I was trying to access, and ":No such file or directory"

Comment: In Unix, you have a shell program, like a command prompt in Windows. Linux has several. Bash is the one you are using.
the error you are getting means 1 of 2 things:  
1) It cannot find the "cd" command  
2) It cannot find the directory you are looking for.Desktop/code  
First, run the 'which cd' command and post the result.  
Second, run the 'ls -la' command and post the result.  
I'm sure we can figure it out if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

If the error message is `bash: cd: DesktopCode: No such file or directory`,
then the most likely explanation is that
you typed `cd Desktop\Code` instead of `cd Desktop/Code`. 
In Unix & Linux,
you must use `/` as a separator between directory names in a pathname.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the slashes, however, now my message says "-bash: cd: Desktop/Code: No such file or directory"

Answer (score -2):

Bash is the shell, or command interpreter that you are using.  That error essentially means that the shell you are using is reporting that it can’t find the directory.

Try this

```
cd ~/Desktop/Code
```

Keep in mind Linux is case sensitive, so if your directory is named code with a lower case “c” the. You will need to modify the command accordingly like this:

```
cd ~/Desktop/code
```

Let me know if that works

Comment: Wow I screwed that up!  I have updated my answer

Comment: Hello! I tried that. however, I just get the same error. It says "-bash: cd:" what I'm trying to access, and ": No such file or directory"

Comment: Did you actually create a folder on your desktop called code at all?